# Have PocketSphinx recognize whether a spoken string contains a word?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, speech-recognition

I'm working on a voice-controlled program for iOS and using Pocketsphinx as my recognition engine. I want it to recognize whether a spoken command contains the word "Morning" and respond with one of the phrases in the morningGreetings array. My code looks like this-

```
if([hypothesis rangeOfString:@"morning"].location == !NSNotFound) {
    NSString *text= [morningGreetings objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [morningGreetings count]];;
    [self.fliteController say:[NSString stringWithFormat:text] withVoice:self.firstVoiceToUse];
}
```

However, with this code the recognizer only exectues the command if "Morning" is the FIRST word in the spoken string. I want it to respond to "Good morning", "Nice morning, isn't it", "How are you this morning?", etc. What can I change to achieve this?

Comment: Oooh, I never knew about PocketSphinx.  Nice find!  [Here is a tutorial on how to integrate it into iOS apps](http://www.rajeevan.co.uk/pocketsphinx_in_iphone/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it to recognize whether a spoken command contains the word "Morning" (...) However, with this code the recognizer only exectues the command if "Morning" is the FIRST word in the spoken string.

Your condition `location == !NSNotFound` is equivalent to `location == 0` because `!NSNotFound` equals 0, therefore it only executes if "morning" is the first word in the string. What you want is `location != NSNotFound`.

Change the condition like so:

```
if ([hypothesis rangeOfString:@"morning"].location != NSNotFound) { ... }
```